# pointer changes unexpectedly despite not being changed out of scope

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing code here to try and replicate virtual memory in C. For some reason, a pointer I create and maintain within main get changed unexpectedly after being passed into a function. Here is my code in main

```
int main(){

    void * a = a_malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    printf("1 a:%p\n",a);//1 a:0x1
    int x = 9;
    int y = 0;
    put_value(a,(void*)&x,sizeof(int));
    printf("2 a:%p\n",a);//2 a:0x1
    get_value(a,(void*)&y,sizeof(int));
    printf("3 a:%p\n",a);//3 a:0x8049050
    printf("y:%d\n",y);//y:9
    printf("4 a:%p\n",a);//4 a:0x8049050
    a_free(a,sizeof(int));

}
```

The code works as expected (y correctly holds the value 9), however, the pointer 'a' gets changed from its initial value (0x1) to a new value (0x8049050) after a call to get_value. Whats interesting though is that it was not changed after put_value, which does an extremely similar thing to get_value, and neither should be able to change the pointer 'a' which is local to main. The code for those two functions is

```
/* The function copies data pointed by "val" to physical
* memory pages using virtual address (va)
*/
void put_value(void *va, void *val, int size) {

   int pages = (int)(ceil((double)size/PGSIZE));
   int c=0;
   for(c=0;c<pages;c++){

       unsigned int addr = (unsigned int)va + (c*PGSIZE);
       void * pa = translate((void*)addr);
       addr = (unsigned int)val + (c*PGSIZE);
       memcpy(pa,(void*)addr,PGSIZE);
       c++;

   }
}


/*Given a virtual address, this function copies the contents of the page to val*/
void get_value(void *va, void *val, int size) {

   int pages = (int)(ceil((double)size/PGSIZE));
   int c=0;
   for(c=0;c<pages;c++){

       unsigned int addr = (unsigned int)va + (c*PGSIZE);
       void * pa = translate((void*)addr);
       addr = (unsigned int)val + (c*PGSIZE);
       memcpy((void*)addr,pa,PGSIZE);
       c++;

   }
}
```

PGSIZE is a header defined value, which is defined in my testing as 4096. translate really is irrelevant here, but just in case

```
/*
The function takes a virtual address and page directories starting address and
performs translation to return the physical address
*/
void *translate(void *va) {

    translation =((page_directory[get_top_bits((unsigned)va)]).pagetable[get_mid_bits((unsigned)va)]).paddr;


    return translation;

}
```

I have stepped through the code multiple times using GDB and I can't find exactly where 'a' is being reset, or even how its being reset. Because it is being reset, the call to a_free segfaults (as it calls translate, which uses the wrong address in trying to access our defined page directory and page tables) Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Given that the code is playing games with pointers, I presume that it inadvertently scribbles on the stack, changing the value of `a`. I'd start by looking at the arguments that you're passing to `memcpy`.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?  Have you tried running it under valgrind or with `-fsanitize=address`?  Have you tried setting a watchpoint on `a` in gdb?

Comment: I'm alarmed that `get_value` and `put_value` are only being told to copy `sizeof(int)` bytes (i.e. 4 bytes), yet they actually copy a whole page.  Something important is sure to get overwritten when you do that.

Comment: Why do you pass different sizes to `a_malloc()` and `a_free()`? Why do you increment `c` in the `for` loop statements and also inside the loop bodies?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the advice I completely forgot about watchpoints :) It seems that the memcpy is what is changing the value, although I'm still not sure why but its a start

Comment: Yeah, the `memcpy` is basically the only thing it can be.  So you have to think about how you're computing the destination address and the size...

Comment: @Blastfurnace the different sizes were for testing purposes, the additional increment of c was an honest mistake that I'm glad you caught

Comment: @NateEldredge you were also correct in the copying of size rather than a whole page. I edited to accompany for the actual size rather than whole pages so hopefully, I wont run into this again while testing. Thanks